# Why don't I have access to the moderator chat room anymore?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, teachers-lounge

I'm still a *moderator pro tempore* [over at Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/109/torben-gundtofte-bruun) and therefore ought to have access to the "Teacher's Lounge" chat room, but when I visit the link I get "access denied".

Is something broken? Has someone fiddled with the room's permissions? Or have I been expelled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied on TL, what gives?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126112/access-denied-on-tl-what-gives) - balpha says he has manually fixed it for anyone affected, though, so I'm not sure why you're still getting the error.

Comment: They put you in a timeout for 2 minutes.  You can say you're sorry afterwards and get back in, I think.

Comment: @JNK: Mods are immune to timeouts.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now, or my ban lifted, or whatever it was.

Comment: I may have missed you when I fixed the moderator accounts after the issue @BoltClock mentioned. Sorry about that.

Comment: @balpha no worries mate!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the setting for "parent site" on your [Stack Exchange chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) account.  If it's not set to the site where you're a moderator you won't have access to the TL.

Comment: I noticed that it had been changed to my Area51 account and changed it back to Parenting, then it seemed to work. I wasn't sure if _that_ was the fix or pure coincidence. Thank you!

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I'm assuming you're back in the TL now?

Comment: As I said, it works now.