# Why was my chat profile changed?

Tags: bug, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access denied on TL, what gives?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126112/access-denied-on-tl-what-gives)

I'm a moderator, but recently I was denied entry in the *Teachers' Lounge,* the moderators' chat room. I recalled that this has happened before, and I found my old MSO question:
[Why don't I have access to the moderator chat room anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126371/why-dont-i-have-access-to-the-moderator-chat-room-anymore)

The answer is simple enough, and it worked so I have access again. But my point of *this* question is:

**Why was my chat profile changed?** 
I'm pretty certain that I didn't fiddle with any of my SE profiles anywhere. If *I* didn't make this change, how did it happen?

Comment: Hit this myself once. It's the bug that keeps on giving.

Comment: You _think_ you're still a moderator....

Comment: @PopularDemand: har har ... I _think!_ ;)

Comment: In his answer for the duplicated question, @balpha explained what happened.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks, that sounds like an explanation. But that other question is set to `status-completed` and so I'm surprised it's still (very rarely) happening.

Comment: balpha said, "I'm not sure I'll be able to find the precise cause." They have fixed it, but they cannot be sure it doesn't happen again, which is what happened to you.