# Chat parent user suddenly changed to Area51

Tags: bug, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Access denied on TL, what gives?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126112/access-denied-on-tl-what-gives)

I have not touched my chat settings at all in months. Today I noticed suddenly that [my chat profile's parent use](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/14671/simon-sheehan)r was set to discuss.area51. I never set this. Why did it change? I know I can change it back, but I'm leaving it as such until I figure out what happened.

My parent user is supposed to be set to Super User. No one else who regulars the Super User rooms seems to have this issue.

[image]

**Update:** Upon changing my parent site back, it now only displays 7 badges, and only has my SU rep, not total.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126133/150235), maybe? (not sure how recently you had logged into chat before this)

Comment: @TimStone Looks right to me, thanks.